# Control Timing of Movie, Gnuplot with C++

Tags: visual-c++, movie

May you tell me how can I control the timing of the movie made of many data files please? It is going so fast that looks weird. I want to make it slow so that I could see the complete pattern. 
Thank you for your time.

**Update**: I am using: `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i %d.gif video2.mpg`

But it gives an error and gives out no output.

Comment: What does your C++ code look like?  What error did you get?  If this is a printf format, it looks like the command you're generating will only convert a single frame (unless you've got animated gifs or something...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Win32 Sleep() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pause for a few milliseconds between frames/plots/data files.

Update:  You didn't mention `ffmpeg` originally, so I thought you were developing your
own C++ playback code.  It appears you're trying to build and execute a `ffmpeg` command from inside your C++ code, instead. According to the [ffmpeg documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC1), the `-r` option controls the frame rate, so just lower it if you want the playback to be slower.

You may need to specify all the GIF file names (via multiple `-i filename` options) in a single `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: May you tell me the syntax for this please? I am using:ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i %d.gif video2.mpg But it gives an error and gives out no output.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. I do have next issue of plotting a no of plots together. Here one blocks the other. I tried with the way how Gnuplot tutorial says<gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/transparent.html>; but I could not get it. Even the codes there do not work. Do you have any idea you can share please?

Comment: @nagendra: I don't think I can help with that one...you should post it as a separate question, and maybe someone else will be able to answer.  By the way, if my answer here was helpful to you, please consider marking it as "accepted".  We'll both get a few reputation points, and it'll help future visitors see that the answer worked for you.

Comment: May you tell me how I can do so?